# Head tag in html page closes programatically after page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, head

My page is located [here](https://wifi.au.dk/testingenv/auto_setup_employee.php) 
As you can see, it doesn't look like it's working properly. This becomes very apparent if you try to open it in an older browser (this is what initially set me off).

I checked the interpreted source code from chrome and it shows me the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <title>Internet adgang - Hurtig opsætning - Ansatte</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

Etc..

Something seems to be closing my head tag which is causing all SORTS of errors:

[W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://wifi.au.dk/testingenv/auto_setup_employee.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services)

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this.

You can see my source code [here](http://pastebin.com/tNXcVL27) (I've scrambled the PHP):

The code above does not contain my body code, as I am fairly sure that has nothing to do with the head tag closing all of a sudden.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/j6FZYPM8) is some source of a page that works just fine:

I am completely baffled by this and I have no idea what to do nor what is causing it. 
Any ideas?

**Solution**

With the help of Buttc4k3 and vogomatix I finally found the solution. As buttc4k3 said, there was an illegal "zero-width no-space" character hidden in the file which didn't show in my sublime text editor. It would only show if you opened the file in Notepad++. I could not understand why this character would appear in google chrome, and not in my source, but after googling it, I found that a file saved in UTF-8 WITH BOM (Byte Order Marking) would save the BOM as a zero-width no-space character! This was where vogomatix saved me and told me that my file was saved with BOM and after recoding it without BOM it works fine.

So - if you have the same problem as me - save your file WITHOUT BOM ENCODING (this can be done in notepad++).

Comment: Always put php code above or beneath your head tag. try of that solves it.

Comment: It looks like you have answer but your confuse why this working in this way. As above state I hope you got reason of why code is working properly http://pastebin.com/j6FZYPM8.

Comment: Very picky but img tags do not close in HTML(5) so they should be <img .... > not <img .... />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the page source of your website and pasted it in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and found a [zero-width no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) in line 3 column 5. It renders invisible in most editors/viewers, but it breaks the HTML parser of the browser. I don't know how or why it got there since I can't find it in the PHP code, but maybe you can find it by opening your code in Notepad++. It renders this character as a tiny dot. If you can't find it, delete everything from and including `<head>` to `<title>` and re-type it.

I hope this works.

PS: Even though it is not the reason why your page is broken, you should add `<html>` and `</html>` to the markup. Most browsers can deal with its absence, but it is there for a reason.

Comment: Thank you, this was also Flixer's answer below and it seemed to fix it.
Removing the ZW NB, moving the PHP to the top of the page and adding <html> tags finally solved my issues.

Comment: Re-opening the issue! While I've gotten the page to work, I am having the same issue with a similar page now: https://wifi.au.dk/testingenv/auto_setup_student.php

I have deleted everything from the first symbol down to <div id="container"> and copied the source from the working page to this page and it STILL doesn't work. I am baffled.

Comment: @BjørnZeiler It's the same character in a different location. This time, it's before the doctype.

Comment: Here is the unedited source: http://pastebin.com/H56a8PNN

Could you find me the character? I simply do not see it.

Comment: Incidentally, the W3C validator also picks up the BOM (Byte Order Mark) in what claims to be a UTF-8 file. The validator specifically mentions that older browsers may have issues with this

Comment: I will look into this, but as it is not causing me issues on the original page, I am assuming that it is not the cause of the issue here.

Comment: More info: I've been trying to find the "hidden character" and when I copy the source code in from google chrome, I can see the hidden character just before the DOCTYPE. HOWEVER, if I copy the code from my source code editor - I do not see the same character anywhere!

I've even tried to do a search for it, using notepad++ it tells me there is no such character in my source, but there is one in the source I copied from google chrome. Why is chrome creating this character?

Comment: Solved! check my initial post for info

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the `<html>` tag.

Current HTML-Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Internet adgang - Hurtig opsætning - Ansatte</title>
```

Must be something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Internet adgang - Hurtig opsætning - Ansatte</title>
        [...]
    </head>
    <body>
        [...]
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have attempted this, no dice.

Comment: There also seem to be some strange characters between `<html>` and `<head>` - if I hex encode it, it returns: `&#xa;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#xfeff;`, apperently `&#xfeff` causes the problem (research: it seems to mean 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE'). Try to delete all characters between <html> and <head> and replace them only with spaces and line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the first part of your site to be as follows:

```
    <?php
   include 'XXXXX';
   include 'XXXXX';
   if(!isset($_GET['lang'])) {
       $lang = "DA";
   } else {
       $lang = $_GET['lang'];
   }
   ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php $lang; ?>">
<head>
    <title><?php echo trans("Internet adgang - Hurtig opsætning - Ansatte", $lang); ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/style.css" media="all">
    <script src="resources/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/au-flowbox-style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/au-flowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/au-flowbox.data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
....
```